# Obtain Motherboard Sensor Data

Tags: c#, .net, sensors, temperature

How can I read data from motherboard sensors in C#?

I mean: CPU temperature, GPU temperature, fan speeds, CPU and GPU usage, etc.

I have Asus P5LD2-X/1333 and [Nvidia GTS 250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_200_series#GeForce_200_Series) 1024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Open Hardware Monitor application. It is open source.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Motherboard Monitor .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbmdotnet/)

Comment: Wow, very outdated, and still uses a shared memory, from the actual MBM app.